# Formatting a cell based off of the rest of the row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet keeping track of the various documents that students of mine have been turning in. The first column contains names and each column after tracks a particular document.

Is there a way for a student's name to be highlighted if any one of the other columns has a checkmark? I, therefore, would like the first cell of a row highlighted if there is an "x" anywhere in the rest of the row.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi Gilmario, yes that's possible. Have a look at this question for example which answers a very similar problem. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134782/conditionally-formatting-a-column-based-on-content-of-nearby-column/134786#134786

Comment: this ^ +1 : The values in the checkboxes (`Menu` > `Insert` > `Checkboxes`) are either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Gilamrio: It'd be great if you could try to apply the method I linked above and update your question with whatever you got to. If you manage to make it work, answer your own question so that it's on the record for others.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you need for range `A1:A` is:

```
=and(A1<>"",counta(B1:J1)<>0)
```

[image]